# Python: module import hierarchy (non-existing modules at startup)

Tags: python, python-3.x, hierarchy, software-design, python-module

There is no quick way to describe this problem, so stay with me! [A similar question was already asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585046/how-do-i-mock-the-hierarchy-of-non-existing-modules), but my use case is a bit different. The easiest way to explain it is by describing an actual use case:

I have a folder with some common utility modules, that are in use by my scripts.

```
commonPythonFiles/
    pathUtils.py
    procUtils.py
    specialModuleUtils.py

    groupedCommonPythonFiles/
        groupUtils1.py
        groupUtils2.py (*)
```

This modules may have cross imports: `procUtils` use functions from `pathUtils.py`, while `groupUtils1.py` use both of them (`procUtils.py` and `pathUtils.py`).

There is a special module, which is not available from the start of the scripts - it is extracted/copied/generated/... in runtime of `main.py` by the use of `specialModuleUtils.py` functions.

```
specialModuleFolder/ # not available from the start
    specialModule.py
```

On the other hand, `groupUtils2.py (*)` is a wrapper of a such `specialModule.py`.

In some worker script (example, `main.py`), this utility modules are needed, hence, they are usually imported at the beginning of the file.

---

**Problem**

```py
#main.py
import pathUtils
import procUtils
import specialModuleUtils
import groupUtils1
import groupUtils2 # (!)

def main():
    # prepare special module
    args = groupUtils1.getSpecialModuleArguments(sys.argv) # might be a lot more than one line to get arguments
    specialModuleUtils.create(args)

    # do some stuff with groupUtils2 which use created special module
    groupUtils2.doSomeStuffWithSpecialModule()
```

You might already suspect the problem I am facing. I am importing module that is not yet available.  `main.py` fails at the `import groupUtils2`, since `specialModuleUtils` is not yet created.

What I actually struggle with is the question: what is the right approach how to handle imports or in general, what is the best module hierarchy for such non-standard cases?

---

**Possible solutions**

- Set a rule: no imports of common modules should be placed in file header.

```py
#main.py
import pathUtils
import procUtils

def main():
    import groupUtils1
    import specialModuleUtils
    # prepare special module
    args = groupUtils1.getSpecialModuleArguments(sys.argv) # might be a lot more than one line to get arguments
    specialModuleUtils.extract(args)

    # do some stuff with groupUtils2 which use created special module
    import groupUtils2
    groupUtils2.doSomeStuffWithSpecialModule()
```

This clutters the functions, duplicate import statements and complicate the use of common utility modules.

- Make special module generation as a prerequisites for a scripts - `main.py` should run in already prepared environment with available `specialModule.py` to import.
  This means, that before any script would be executed, some other script/job/process needs to be run that would prepare `specialModule.py`
  Also, this script would also be limited in usage of common python files, otherwise it might fail in the same way as `main.py`.

Since there is some logic needed to extract this special module (`args = groupUtils1.getSpecialModuleArguments(sys.argv)`), simple virtual environments are not an option (or are they?).

**Q**: What I actually struggle with is the question: what is the right approach how to handle imports or in general, what is the best module hierarchy for such non-standard cases?

Comment: What about re-evaluating your entire design, so that you just have a plain dict in one of those modules that can be populated, instead of a "special module"? A module is basically just a shared namespace dict anyway...

Comment: Maybe a redesign will get you rid of cross-imports.

Comment: There is number of "common" files because this allow us to pack functions to modules, grouped by functionality. That way the code is not duplicated, which was the basic idea of common files. 'specialModule' is actually also some sort of common file, but is versioned (python SDK API of some larger software) - meaning, it is usually dynamically imported from a specific path.The problem is, that it is very inconvenient to add this path and actual dynamically import this module at the very beginning of some script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is of course only the import of the generated file that must be deferred, either by having `groupUtils2` import it only inside its functions (or as an explicit initialization step that *assigns* the imported module with `global`) or by importing (just) `groupUtils2` in `main` once its eager import of `specialModule` can succeed.  Neither of these is a profound reorganization.

Comment: I am not sure qhat you mean by: "(or as an explicit initialization step that assigns the imported module with global)". Anyway, is importing modules inside functions considered a bad practise?

Comment: @schperplata: The explicit initialization would be a function `groupUtils2.init` that performed the `import` once for all the other functions in the module.  Imports in functions are fine—they’re probably just as fast as using the global import, and they can be useful for limiting/deferring dependencies, although they can also be visually distracting.